# Why is pronunciation of rough and though different?

Tags: pronunciation

Why is "ough" pronounced so differently in rough and though and thought?

Comment: Not to mention _bough_ and _lough_ and _thorough_ and _hiccough_ and _cough_ and _through_, of course. This particular combination of letters is perhaps the best-known and most commonly-cited and described case in existence of English orthography being hopeless – have you tried looking somewhere like dictionaries or Wikipedia to find an answer before asking here? Please edit your question to include what you’ve find and what remains unclear to you after reading what you’ve found. As it is currently worded, the question is likely to be closed for lack of research.

Comment: The question to ask is not why they are pronounced differently, but why they are spelled the same, to which the standard answer is simple that English spelling is only loosely connected to pronunciation.